# How can use Foreground Service in Android 12+

Tags: android, service, foreground-service

How can Use Foreground Service in Android 12 without Error for Api 23+  With notification.

Answer (score -2):

This example help

In MainActivity :

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
    
    
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String MESSAGE_STATUS = "message_status";
    TextView tvStatus;
    Button btnSend;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tvStatus = findViewById(R.id.tvStatus);
        btnSend = findViewById(R.id.btnSend);
//        final WorkManager mWorkManager = WorkManager.getInstance();
//        final OneTimeWorkRequest mRequest = new OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(NotificationWorker.class).build();






        btnSend.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//                mWorkManager.enqueue(mRequest);


                //Start our own service
                if ( isServiceRunning( MyService.class) ) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "وضعیت روشن است امکان سرویس جدید نیست"  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MyService.class);
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                        startForegroundService(intent);
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Running .... "  , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }
    
    // http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/andorid-how-to-check-service-is-running-or-not/
    private boolean isServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
        ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
        for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
            if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }


}//class
```

Create a Service :

MyService.java

```
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;

public class MyService extends Service {

    String channelId = "task_channel";
    String channelName = "task_name";

    public MyService() {
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new
                    NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName,
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        }

        showNotification("WorkManager", "Message has been Sent");

            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        int cou=0;
                        while (true) {
                            Log.i("mohsennnn : ", "me --> " +  cou);
                            cou++;
                            Thread.sleep(500);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.i("mohsennn Service", e.toString());
                    }
                }
            }).start();

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    private void showNotification(String task, String desc) {
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new
                    NotificationChannel(channelId, channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
            manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext(), channelId)
                .setContentTitle(task)
                .setContentText(desc)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
//        manager.notify(1, builder.build());
        startForeground(1 , builder.build());
    }//showNotification

}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Foreground_service_with_notification">

        <service
            android:name=".MyService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true"></service>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

activity_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvStatus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSend"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_chainStyle="packed" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSend"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#000"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:text="Send Notification"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvStatus" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```